# Deadline-free bounties

Tags: discussion

<sub>N.B.: This is inspired by [this post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadline) over on Programming Puzzles and Code Golf.</sub>

## Purpose:

If you have a post that you want answered, you can offer a dead-line free bounty on it.  Simply post a single line under **Bounties Offered** in a bullet heading which will include:

1. The amount of the bounty proffered
2. The name of the user offering (with a link to their profile)
3. A brief description of the qualifying requirements
4. (*Optional*) a link to an answer to this question which defines the particular qualifications for your bounty

Example (***For Example Purposes ONLY***):

- **500 points** offered by [anonymous2](https://iot.stackexchange.com/users/49/anonymous2) for the first person who definitively answers [What personal information is stored on my amazon Echo?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-personal-information-is-stored-on-my-amazon-echo) using official sources.

## Rules

1. Only offer a bounty you *can* award.  (You must have rep points to cover it.)
2. The bounties never expire.
3. Your word is your bond.  No one can force you to award your bounty if someone qualifies: your honesty and reputation (*not* rep points) are at stake.  Please be honest.  N.B.:  This also means there is no guarantee that you *will* receive a bounty for qualifying.
4. If you lose interest in your bounty, you may remove it, but if someone has already qualified, you must award it.
5. Be definitive.  Make sure that your readers can tell exactly what is expected from a qualifying answer.

## Offered:

- **50 points** offered by [Aurora0001](https://iot.stackexchange.com/users/12/aurora0001) for *any* answer which adds **detailed, canonical** information on [Securing small home automation setup](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/9/securing-small-home-automation-setup). ([see more](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/a/241/12))*

## Bounties Awarded:

- **50 rep** awarded by Aurora0001 for [Gilles' answer to Securing Small Home Automation Setup](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/150/49)

<sub>* Recurring bounty</sub>

Answer (score 6):

### Bounty for [Securing small home automation setup](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/9/securing-small-home-automation-setup)

**50 points** for any answer which is:

- widely applicable to many smart homes
- likely to be a *real problem* that needs securing against
- clear, and provides instructions on how to solve the problem.

This bounty will be recurring; I will reward any and all good answers to this question.